# Twilio Call Error: Temporary unavailable (Mobile SDK) while registering in custom application

Tags: swift, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

We tried the official demo of VoIP calling in iOS([link](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-ios)) in the following ways and checked the results:
Using static token generated for device-specific identity.
Device A: application in one client device.
Device B: application in another client device

Scenario: 1 (Demo app )

1. Calling from device A to devise B: call was successful.
2. Deregistered the token in B by invalid for logout
3. Now calling from A to B - (Call Error:20104), Access Token expired or expiration date invalid. (as we have deregistered it’s also valid)

Scenario: 2 (Our main app)

1. Login in both device
2. Call from A to B (successful)
3. Logout in B
4. Call from A to B (not available)
5. Again login to device B with a successful registration message.
6. Now calling from device A to B ((Call Error:20104), Access Token expired or expiration date invalid)
7. The above point no 6 should work but it’s not working.

The demo code works but when we are adding login and logout functions in a custom app and adding the same codebase like the one I have created an instance class for call manager to add call functionality throughout the application but this thing is causing issues and showing temporarily unavailable.

Comment: In which device are you getting the 20104 error? How are you generating the access token?

Comment: It's in iPhone XR iOS 15 and I am using a python server code to get the access token and calling this API from mobile : https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-python/blob/master/server.py

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant device A or device B in your example.